# Integrate Apache storm with zookeeper in windows

Tags: java, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

Can anyone help me how to integrate storm with zookeeper in windows.

I try to find the find a good installation steps for production in windows but I can't.

Write now I have installed stand  alone zookeeper and I am trying to configure it in the `storm.yaml`.

sample code I tried :

```
 storm.zookeeper.servers:
   - "127.0.0.1"
    - "server2"

storm.zookeeper.port: 2180 
nimbus.host: "localhost"
```

If any body knows please help me.

Comment: Next time on words, to highlight code use `ctrl+k` , not `#`

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps for complete installation of storm with zookeeper in windows
1. create a zoo.cfg file under /conf directory of zookeeper.
here are the configuration entries

```
# The number of milliseconds of each tick
tickTime=2000
# The number of ticks that the initial 
# synchronization phase can take
initLimit=10
# The number of ticks that can pass between 
# sending a request and getting an acknowledgement
syncLimit=5
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
dataDir=D:\\workspace\\zk-data
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
```

2.run the zookeeper by executing the zkServer.bat in /bin directory

3.create the storm.yaml file in /conf directory of the apache-storm
here are the configuration entries

```
########### These MUST be filled in for a storm configuration
storm.zookeeper.servers:
    - "localhost"

#supervisor.slots.ports:
#    - 6700
#    - 6701
#    - 6702
#   - 6703
storm.local.dir: D:\\workspace\\storm-data
nimbus.host: "localhost"
# 
#
```

4.run  the below commands from the command prompt

```
 a. bin\storm nimbus
 b. bin\storm supervisor
 c. bin\storm ui
```

5. hit the browser with localhost:8080 to see the nimbus ui

6.make sure your JAVA_HOME path does not have any space. otherwise storm command 
will not run.